# Adding emails to the calendar event - Intent. The emails do not get populated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to add emails to a calendar event and fire an Intent but unfortunately, the emails do not get populated. Followed the code snippet from the android documentaion linked here - [Use an Intent to insert an Event](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#intent-insert)

Snippet :

```
val startMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val endMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com")
startActivity(intent)
```

There was an issue raised here years ago (2014) and someone recently said that they'll fix it but not at priority. [Issue linked here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37013694)

Is there a workaround for this at the moment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "someone recently said that they'll fix it but not at priority" -- that is not what that last comment means. That last comment is a very polite form of "this is not getting fixed". Also, please bear in mind that there are any number of apps that might handle that `Intent`, and what extras they support are up to them.

Comment: Yes I do understand that there are multiple apps that can handle the calendar intent but if we take Google Calendar in this case, then technically the above snippet should work right? It does populate all the other fields except the emails.

Comment: "then technically the above snippet should work right?" -- my guess is that this is a long-standing documentation bug and that Google Calendar has never supported `EXTRA_EMAIL` (given that it didn't 7 years ago and apparently does not now). Bear in mind that Google Calendar is a separate product and is not part of the Android SDK, so the Google Calendar app developers can do whatever they want.